# convert curl to php OAuth2.0 Token Generate Error

Tags: php, ssl, curl

```
<?php

$certFile = "/etc/apache2/ssl/thasaix/thasaix_com.crt";
$keyFile = "/etc/apache2/ssl/thasaix/thasaix.com.key";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://openapi-test.kasikornbank.com/v2/oauth/token');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic R1FRWkZWcGpJQ0E5Y2xScUFQZVowODhSQTVYTFgzNzk6QTNLNkxjVHU3OTZ1QTZtxxyy';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $response;

?>
```

curl --cert /etc/apache2/ssl/thasaix/thasaix_com.crt 
--key /etc/apache2/ssl/thasaix/thasaix.com.key 
--location --request POST 'https://openapi-test.kasikornbank.com/v2/oauth/token' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--header 'Authorization: Basic R1FRWkZWcGpJQ0E5Y2xScUFQZVowODhSQTVYTFgzNzk6QTNLNkxjVHU3OTZ1QTZtxxyy' 
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'

the result is

{ "code": "openapi_error", "message": "OAuth2.0 Token Generate Error" }

Answer (score 0):

use these headers like

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Basic R1FRWkZWcGpJQ0E5Y2xScUFQZVowODhSQTVYTFgzNzk6QTNLNkxjVHU3OTZ1QTZtxxyy',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
);
```

Comment: the result is the same  { "code": "openapi_error", "message": "OAuth2.0 Token Generate Error" }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'

Should be body part then I change code  and it work

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
```